# Trying to get $(document).on('Click') to work for a p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my document.on function to work when the user clicks on the p tag that has a class called card.  So far the function is non responsive.  What should I change so the function will respond when I click on the p tag that has a class called card.  Here is my HTML and JQuery code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Contacts">
    <title>Contacts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('button').click(function(){
            var first = $('input.first').val();
            var last = $('input.last').val();
            var desc = $('textarea').val();

            $('div.right').append("<p class='card'><h1>"+ first +' '+last+"</h1><h4>'Click for description!'</h4></p><p class='back'>"+desc+"</p>");

            return false; 
        });

        $(document).on('click', 'p.card', function(){ //this is the function I am trying to get to work.  
            alert("test");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left">
            <form action="#">
                <p >First name: <input type="text" name="fname" class="first"></p>
                <p >Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" class="last"></p>
                <p class="desc">Description:</p> 
                <p><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></p>
                <button>Add User</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my css code

```
*{  
/*  outline: 2px dotted red;*/
    border: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div.wrapper{
    width: 970px;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

div.left{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.right{

    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}   


p{
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 400px;
}

p.email{
    margin-left: 45px;
}

button{
    margin: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}

div.card{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

p.back{
    display: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

textarea{
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Please make sure the jquery library path is correct or not?

Comment: Tell me which jquery versiion you are using?

Comment: @SudharsanS, I am using version three and my jquery path works.  I tested it

Comment: Using developer tools inpsection, you'll see your added html is `<p class="card"></p><h1> </h1><h4>'Click for description!'</h4><p></p><p class="back"></p>` ... so the p.card is empty, very hard to click ... looks like jQuery append is dumber than dishwater

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow the `p.class` you were appending was broken, it was below the other elements and was not being identified as the sender by jQuery event.

The following works fine:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Contacts">
        <title>Contacts</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('button').click(function(){
                var first = $('input.first').val();
                var last = $('input.last').val();
                var desc = $('textarea').val();
                var p = $('<p class="card">');
                p.append("<h1>"+ first +' '+last+"</h1><h4>'Click for description!'</h4><p class='back'>"+desc+"</p>");
                $('div.right').append(p);
                return false;
            });
          
            $(document).on('click', 'p.card', function(){ //this is the function I am trying to get to work.  
                alert("test");

            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left">
            <form action="#">
                <p >First name: <input type="text" name="fname" class="first"></p>
                <p >Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" class="last"></p>
                <p class="desc">Description:</p> 
                <p><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></p>
                <button>Add User</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like You're misusing the header tags.

I tried your DOM structure, and what's happening is that when Firefox/Chrome sees an invalid `<h1>` tag inside the `<p>`, it automatically closes the `<p>` tag. You can clearly see this in Developer Tools.

You should use `<span>` tags instead of header tags, check this [it Works here](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/6u8oyxvq/1/)

**JS CODE:**

```
 $('div.right')
 .append('<p class="card"><span>'+first+'<==>'+last+'</span>Click for Description!!!</p>');
```

Answer (score 2):

your code were not right , the appending elements not formatted as your wish , thats why the click function not working, check the below snippt i have fixed your code, hope fully this will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('button').click(function(){
  var first = $('input.first').val();
  var last = $('input.last').val();
  var desc = $('textarea').val();

  $('div.right').append('<p class="card"></p>');
   $('.card').html("<h1> first +' '+last</h1><h4>Click for description!'</h4><p class='back'>+desc+</p>"
  );
   
 });

 $(document).on('click', 'p.card', function(){ //this is the function I am trying to get to work.  
  alert("test");

 });
});
```

```css
* {
 /*  outline: 2px dotted red;*/
 border: 0 none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
div.wrapper {
 width: 970px;
 min-height: 100px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
div.left {
 border: 2px solid black;
 width: 500px;
 display: inline-block;
}
div.right {
 width: 200px;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100px;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding-right: 100px;
 text-align: center;
}
p {
 margin-left: 80px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 font-size: 20px;
 width: 400px;
}
p.email {
 margin-left: 45px;
}
button {
 margin: 30px;
 height: 20px;
 width: 100px;
 margin-left: 75px;
 text-align: center;
}
div.card {
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100px;
 text-align: center;
}
p.back {
 display: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 text-align: center;
}
textarea {
 border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <form action="#">
      <p >First name:
        <input type="text" name="fname" class="first">
      </p>
      <p >Last name:
        <input type="text" name="lname" class="last">
      </p>
      <p class="desc">Description:</p>
      <p>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
      </p>
      <button>Add User</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="right"> </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using developer tools inpsection, you'll see your added html is

```
<p class="card"></p><h1> </h1><h4>'Click for description!'</h4><p></p><p class="back"></p>`
```

No matter what I've tried, I can't get Firefox to create insert that html as you want it!! it's like it doesn't want to put h1/h4 inside a `p` so decides to close the `p` early!

change to

```
$('div.right').append("<div class='card'><h1>"+ first +' '+last+"</h1><h4>'Click for description!'</h4></div><p class='back'>"+desc+"</p>");
```

and it all goes good - indeed, it's odd, that you already have css for div.card, but not p.card!!

Comment: I tricked it in my answer by first creating the `p` alone and then adding the element into it. I'm still puzzled on why the append did not work as expected!

Comment: Because h inside p is not valid html, and jquery dont want to produce invalid html output?

Comment: That's the most probable, still it's dumb as you can trick it very easily as I did.

Comment: @sinisake - it's not jQuery that stops this happening ... using `insertAdjacentHTML` also produces the same result - it's the browser that is sanitising the markup :p

Answer (score 0):

Wrap card with `<div/>` instead of `<p/>` and it should work. As you have other block elements inside `<p/>`. It's breaking your html.

```
$('div.right').append("<div class='card'><h1>"+ first +' '+last+"</h1><h4>'Click for description!'</h4><p class='back'>"+desc+"</p></div>");
```

And then change `'p.card'` to `'div.card'`.

Comment: When I remove return false, the page refreshes and all the data disappears

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in Javascript and impliment jquery in the function:

```
var div = document.getElementById('someid');
function foo(e) {
    //Jquery Here
}
div.addEventListener('click', foo);
```

This is what I use for a lot of my functions.